# Failure to load .CSV file into 2d array

Tags: java, arrays, csv, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm trying to load a CSV file into a 2d array, but when I go to call it in main I receive the error

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0

In my code while the file has a next line, it splits up the line, stores it in a string array which will in turn be moved to the 2D array. I don't understand how there can be an error. Anyone willing to explain or am I just very dense?

```
public int rows = 0;
public int cols = 0;
public String[][] filetable = new String[rows][cols];

 public void set_Array(File example)
{        
    try 
    {
         FileReader file = new FileReader(example);
         Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);  

         if(sc.hasNextLine())
         { 
             String[] tokens = sc.nextLine().split(",");
             cols = tokens.length;
             rows++;
         }

         while(sc.hasNextLine())
         {
             rows++;
             sc.nextLine();                 
         }
    } 
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
    {
        System.out.println(e);
    }

}
 public void to_Array(File example)
    {
         try 
        {
             FileReader file = new FileReader(example);
             Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);

             int r = 0;
             while(sc.hasNextLine())
             {
                 String[] tokens = sc.nextLine().split(",");
                 for(int c = 0; c < cols; c++)
                   {filetable[r][c] = tokens[c];}

                 r++;
             }

        }

                catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: The problem is probably with `filetable`, but you never show us how `filetable` is set up.  Also, you say you use another method to compute `cols`, but you don't let us know what that is.  Bottom line: you haven't given us nearly enough info to help you.

Comment: Sorry!! Will fix that now!

Comment: When you create `filetable`, `rows` and `cols` are both 0, because `filetable` is created when your object is first constructed.  Try assigning `filetable = new String[rows][cols];` after `rows` and `cols` have been computed.  Also, your method requires going through the whole input file twice, which isn't ideal.  Using an `ArrayList` would help you create an array whose size can grow dynamically, so that you don't have to precompute the number of rows.

Comment: You can either use ArrayList as ajb suggested or you can move String[][] filetable = new String[rows][cols]; inside your to_Array() method and call to_Array after set_Array() has finished executing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know in which order you are calling `set_Array` and `to_Array` methods. But I guess, the problem is that you are essentially creating a 2D array of 0 rows and 0 sizes as `public String[][] filetable = new String[rows][cols];` is called when `rows=0` and `cols=0`. To rectify, call your `set_Array` method to assign proper values to `rows` and `cols` and then instantiate your 2D array inside your `to_Array` method.

```
public void to_Array(File example)
{// Now rows and cols will have proper values assigned
String[][] filetable = new String[rows][cols];
     try 
    {
         FileReader file = new FileReader(example);
         Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);

         int r = 0;
         while(sc.hasNextLine())
         {
             String[] tokens = sc.nextLine().split(",");
             for(int c = 0; c < cols; c++)
               {filetable[r][c] = tokens[c];}

             r++;
         }

    }

            catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
    {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```